Upgrading Microsoft.ServiceBus package to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus for Dead Letter Queue
I am working on an old Web API project built on** .NET Framework 4.8**. I have the below code to get dead letter queue information from Azure Service Bus. Currently, we are using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package for that. But this package is deprecated so I have installed Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus and uninstalled the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package. Now I am getting errors in several places of my current code. Here is my current code:
public async Task<List<TopicInfo>> GetDeadLetterQueueData()
{
    var topicInfos = new List<TopicInfo>();
    var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_serviceBusConnectionString);
    var topicDescriptions = namespaceManager.GetTopics().ToList();

    foreach (var topicDescription in topicDescriptions)
    {
        var subscriptionDescriptions = await namespaceManager.GetSubscriptionsAsync(topicDescription.Path);
        foreach (var subscriptionDescription in subscriptionDescriptions)
        {
            if (subscriptionDescription.MessageCount > 0 && !subscriptionDescription.Name.Equals("Fluff", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                topicInfos.Add(new TopicInfo
                {
                    // Get Topic Information
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return topicInfos;
}

I am getting an error on the below line:
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_serviceBusConnectionString);


It's saying that NamespaceManager does not exist in current
context

How can I resolve this problem. I am very new in Azure.

Replace the deprecated NamespaceManager with ServiceBusAdministrationClient from the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package to manage topics and subscriptions. Use GetTopicsAsync() and GetSubscriptionsAsync() to retrieve topic and subscription details in the new SDK.

If possible, can you share your GitHub repo?

The Azure SDK team has provided a migration guide from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. Reading the migration guide should help answer most of the migration-related questions.
There's also a migration guide from the oldest SDK, WindowsAzure.ServiceBus in case you have some of that code.
